# bash alias quotation mark escape

Tags: bash, escaping, alias

I am new here.  I want to set up an alias in my `.bashrc` like the following:

```
alias printQt="echo ..."
```

which prints the following:

```
X="a bcx "
```

However, it seems the nested quotation mark escaping is very hard to do. What do I need to write in place of the `...` above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that this is what you want:

```
$ alias printQt="echo 'X=\"a bcx \"'"
$ printQt 
X="a bcx "
```

Within double quotes, other double quotes need to be escaped. The single quotes go around the whole string that you want to echo.

Note that you can always just use a function instead:

```
printQt() { echo 'X="a bcx "'; }
```

Now the code is no longer a string, so things are a bit simpler.

Comment: Thanks. I did use a function but feel it is ugly. Your first solution is great.

Comment: The function is the preferred replacement for almost all aliases.

Comment: Thanks a lot, guys!